# Subclass of AbstractController requires explicit render call

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to figure out how to render views from models in the best way. The best approach that I have found so far is to extend AbstactController because then I can structure the code as MVC. Now, only a slight issue remains: I have to call render explicitly in my action methods to render the view (which is not needed in Rails).

For example: to create an alternative to ActionMailer I implemented an EmailsController class which extends AbstractController.

```
class EmailsController < AbstractController::Base
  include AbstractController::Rendering
  include AbstractController::Layouts
  include AbstractController::Helpers
  include AbstractController::Translation
  include AbstractController::AssetPaths
  include ActionController::UrlWriter

  helper ApplicationHelper

  self.view_paths = "app/views"

  def notification
    render 'notification'
  end
end
```

How can I get rid of the render call?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to also include `include ActionController::ImplicitRender`. It renders default view if response body was not rendered yet: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5b2eb64ceb08cd005dc06b721935de5853971473/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb#L5